# Customise Windows' minimize all shortcut key or alternative without Windows logo?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently using an old Toshiba laptop which somehow has Windows Vista running on it. Unfortunately this laptop doesn't have a Windows key on the keyboard.

I'm normally a heavyweight user of the Windows+D keyboard shortcut which minimises all windows and shows the desktop. There are alternatives that I know of, such as Windows+M and Alt+Space+N. But Windows+D is easier to type with your left hand whilst the right hand can stay on the mouse.

Because I don't have a Windows key, is anyone aware of a way that I can re-map say Ctrl+Alt+X to minimise all windows and show the desktop?

I could probably easily write an AutoIt script to minimise all windows, then allocate a keyboard shortcut to that script. But is there any way of doing this without using a separate script to actually minimise the windows?
For example, a keyboard re-map utility with the minimise functionality built-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Autohotkey, as suggested bu Trudbert, but in your case I think it would be way easier to do it in the registry directly.

In which case you should look at [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/), which is the software recommended by the AHK developers to do such changes easily. Doing it manually is possible but more complex. You can take a look at [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=56216#p56216) post on the AHK forums for an example of how it's done.

Comment: A front-end to a registry edit... perfect!

Answer (score 4):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) allows you to define keyboard shortcuts:

```
^!x::#d
```

would do the remap you want